# Linux/bash does not execute the executable that "which" tells me

Tags: linux, bash, path, which

**Observation:**
I have an executable named foo, located in /b/foo. It is compiled against an old header of a dynamic library, causing it to segfault when executed:

```
$ foo
Segmentation fault. // Expected behaviour.
```

Now, I compile a new version of foo to /a/foo against the new dynamic library that should execute just fine. Directory a/ is in my $PATH before b/, so /a/foo should be selected:

```
$ which foo
/a/foo
```

When I execute foo, the following happens:

```
$ foo
Segmentation fault.
```

Therefore, it seems that /b/foo gets executed, whereas "which" tells me that /a/foo should be executed.
To make things weirder, when I run the full path $(which /a/foo), things run fine:

```
$ /a/foo
OK!

$ cp /a/foo .
$ ./foo
OK!
```

---

To go yet one step further, if I now delete /a/foo:

```
$ rm /a/foo
```

Then /b/foo must surely be chosen, right?

```
$ which foo
/b/foo
$ foo
bash: /a/foo: No such file or directory
$ $(which foo)
Segmentation fault. // Expected result.
```

Nope!

**Fix:**
Source .bash_profile and .bashrc and the problem disappears.

**Reproducibility:**
Every time. Just remove /a/foo, source ~/.bash_profile, create /a/foo, and the above observation re-occurs.

**Question:**
Does anyone have an idea what went wrong here?

**Hypothesis:**
"which" is up-to-date, but the system chooses based on "what was used to be the case".
In my example above, /a/foo did not yet exist when the terminal was opened: I had only just created it. Therefore, when /a/foo was created, "which" did detect /a/foo, but the system still chose /b/foo, because it was somehow out of sync?
**But why is the system out of sync?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bash caches the location of commands.  Use `hash foo` to force it to update the cache.

Also, `which` is a separate command that doesn't tell you where your shell is actually looking; it just consults the `$PATH` environment variable. In bash, you should use `type` instead:

```
$ type foo
foo is hashed (/a/foo)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Just to add to your answer: After curiously trying some more, I found that a _new_ executable is automatically added to the cache [hence I never noticed this before], whereas if an _existing_ executable is changed/deleted, the cache will not know.

Comment: That's just how all caches work: the first time some function is asked for a result, it does some work to determine that result, and then it remembers that answer so it doesn't have to redo the work.  

In this case, when you type a command, bash first looks in the cache. If it's not there, it searches the `$PATH`. If it finds it, it stores the result in the cache for next time.